# Pandas DataFrame: how to fill `nan` with 0s but only nans existing between valid values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I'd like to do:

```
In [2]: b = pd.DataFrame({"a": [np.nan, 1, np.nan, 2, np.nan]})
Out[2]:
      a
0   nan
1 1.000
2   nan
3 2.000
4   nan
```

Expected output:

```
      a
0   nan
1 1.000
2   0
3 2.000
4   nan
```

As you can see here, only nans that are surrounded by valid values are replaced with 0.

How can I do this?

- `df.interpolate(limit_area='inside')`  looks good to me but it doesn't have an argument to fill with 0s...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Method 1: `interpolate`, `isna`, `notna` and `loc`

You can use `interpolate` and then check which positions have `NaN` in your original data, and which are filled in your interpolated, then replace those values with `0`:

```
s = df['a'].interpolate(limit_area='inside')

m1 = b['a'].isna()
m2 = s.notna()

df.loc[m1&m2, 'a'] = 0

     a
0  NaN
1  1.0
2  0.0
3  2.0
4  NaN
```

---

#### Method 2: `shift` and `loc`:

An easier method would be to check if previous row and next row are `not NaN` and fill those positions with `0`:

```
m1 = df['a'].shift().notna()
m2 = df['a'].shift(-1).notna()
m3 = df['a'].isna()

df.loc[m1&m2&m3, 'a'] = 0

     a
0  NaN
1  1.0
2  0.0
3  2.0
4  NaN
```

Comment: Oops, I think you've made a mistake on method2: you need to add `m3 = df['a'].isnull()`!

Comment: Yes agreed, edited. Ps it's adviced to use `isna` over `isnull` since it's more consistent with `dropna` and `fillna` @user3595632

Answer (score 0):

```
b = pd.DataFrame({"a": [np.nan, 1, np.nan, 2, np.nan,3,np.nan]})
a = b[b['a'].isna()]
print('After :',b['a'])

#######Solution One######
for x in a.iterrows() :
    pre = x[0] - 1
    post = x[0]  +1
    if pre < 0 or post >= len(b['a']) :
        pass
    else :
        if  not(np.isnan(b.iloc[pre,0])) and not(np.isnan(b.iloc[post,0])) :
            b.iloc[x[0],0] = 0


print('Before :',b['a'])

######Solution Two#######
def series_extract(index, series):
    return map(np.isnan, series[[index-1, index, index+1]])

def fill_in_between_na(df, column):
    series = df[column]
    index = []
    for i in range(1,len(series)-1) :
        mask = np.array([False,True,False]) == np.array(series_extract(i, series))
        if all(mask):
            index.append(i)
    df[column][index] = 0
    return df

fill_in_between_na(b, 'a')
print('Before :',b['a'])
```